Change basepath of APISIX dashboard
I have a APISIX gateway running on remote_host:9080, and the related dashboard on remote_host:9000.
I tried the following configuration:
>  {   "uri": "/apisix",   "name": "Apisix Dashboard route",  
>     "methods": ["GET"],    
>     "plugins": {
>     "proxy-rewrite": {
>     "headers": {
>         "add": {
>           "X-Request-ID": "112233"
>         },
>         "remove": [
>           "X-test"
>         ],
>         "set": {
>           "X-Api-Engine": "apisix",
>           "X-Api-Version": "v1",
>           "X-Api-useless": ""
>         }
>       },
>       "uri": "/"}   },   
>.    "upstream_id": "508593773039584280",   
>.    "labels": {
>     "API_VERSION": "0.2"   },   
>.    "status": 1 }

The request is correctly redirect to the service but the login page stuck in charging.
There is a way to access the dashboard by querying remote_host:9080/apisix, and have the service work correctly?
I also thought to change the base_path of APISIX apisix to localhost:9080/apisix, but I cannot find the setting to change to do so.
